# Multiplication gives wrong output in java

Tags: java, math

**Code**

```
    public class main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(1101101101*10);
        }
    
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
-1873890878
```

[image: calci]

I do the same thing in python it gives the output.

```
     Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2251]
    (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    C:\Users\pradeep>python
    Python 3.10.8 (tags/v3.10.8:aaaf517, Oct 11 2022, 16:50:30) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> 1101101101*10
    11011011010
```

How can I solve this in java ?

Comment: You've encountered *integer overflow*, the topic of numerous questions and answers on this site, and covered in a myriad of textbooks and websites.  Let your search engine be your friend.

Comment: `Math.multiplyExact( 1101101101 , 10 )` throws an exception if you overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Any number written literally like `1101101101` or `10` is considered an Integer by default in java. And Integer in java represents any whole number from -2147483648 to 2147483647. your argument makes the output exceed the said range, your IDE probably raise a warning that said `Numeric overflow in expression`, maybe you didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

> Below code might solve your problem .

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Long longVal = 1101101101l;
    System.out.println(longVal*10);
}
```